# How to make objects properties reactive when they rely on an external object?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, javascript-objects, vue-router, dynamic-arrays

tldr:

`User` is a global object.

If I change `show` value, the component will update instantly, that's OK.
What I want to gain is like "When `User.isLoggedIn()` becomes false, the `Log out` element must hide. When it becomes true, the element must show and `Login/Signup` must hide." In my app, this goal would transform into another, "When I'm redirecting from `login`,`signup`, or`signout` pages, these properties(and state of the button) must be updated."

`Toolbar.Vue`.

Script:

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            items: [
                {title: 'Questions', to: '/questions', show: true},
                {title: 'Ask question', to: '/askQuestion', show: true},
                {title: 'Categories', to: '/categories', show: true},
                //  only F5.
                {title: 'Login/Signup', to: '/login', show: !User.isLoggedIn()},
                {title: 'Log out', to: '/logout', show: User.isLoggedIn()},
            ]
        }
    },

}
```

Piece of markup:

```
<router-link
          v-for="item in items"
          :key="item.title"
          :to="item.to"
          v-if="item.show"
  >
```

You know, I'm trying to do the 'logout thing' with vue. I have that `Toolbar` component with `router-link` to `Logout` component.

***Note***: I don't import `User` class in my component directly, but I do it in my app.js. like this:

```
import User from './helpers/AppUser';
window.User = User;
```

So, I think that everybody has access to the right `User`. Furthermore, this class is just a grouped couple of methods. Main method is `retrieve()`.

In my `Logout` component there's the code:

```
beforeMount() {
    User.logout();
    router.push('questions')
  // window.location = '/questions'
    }
```

So, when I go logout, all is fine (I'm returning to questions page), but my `Log out` button is still here.

`User.isLoggedIn()` works properly (When I `F5` my page, all is fine).

I also mentioned that if I change `show` value, the component will update instantly, that's OK.

That try also doesn't work:

```
    {title: 'Login/Signup', to: '/login', show: ()=> !this.isLoggedIn},
            {title: 'Log out', to: '/logout', show: ()=> this.isLoggedIn},
        ],
    }
},

computed:{
    isLoggedIn: function() {
        return User.isLoggedIn();
  },
```

My temp solution is using `window.location = '/questions'` instead of `vue-router`.
Maybe I need some watchers, or add User in my global Vue... I don't know.

Update: User class.

```
/**
 * Class-helper for managing user login/signup part. Also represents the user.
 */
class AppUser {

    constructor() {
        this.storageKey = 'appUser';
    }


    /**
     * retrieves user data from localStorage. if none stored, returns null
     * @return {object}|{null}
     */
    retrieve() {
        let data = {};

        try {
            data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.storageKey));
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        } finally {
            // console.log(data)
        }

        return data;
    }

    /**
     * clears localStorageEntry
     */
    clear() {
        localStorage.removeItem(this.storageKey);
    }

    /**
     * @return boolean
     */
    hasId() {
        let data = this.retrieve();
        return data === null ? false : data.hasOwnProperty('id');
// if id then return true
    }

    /**
     * @return boolean
     */
    hasToken() {
        let data = this.retrieve();
        return data === null ? false : data.hasOwnProperty('jwt');
// if token then return true
    }


    isLoggedIn() {
        // console.log('in user.isLoggedIn')
        // try {
            return this.hasToken() && this.hasId();
        // }
        // catch (e) {
        //  console.log(e);
        // }
    }
}


export default AppUser = new AppUser();
```

Comment: Hi. I'd need to know where User is stored. It seems you're not using a store for common state management, is User just a global object?
And I also need to know how you update the status of the User.

Comment: Can you show your User class and `User.isLoggedIn()` method?

Comment: @ittus, I updated the post.

Comment: @Renaud, I updated the post.

Comment: Vue.set not working? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: @Estradiaz, if I directly change the `show` property, it is updated instantly, all is Ok. In my app, I want to update these properties every time when I am redirected from `login`, `signup`, or `signout` page

Comment: My advice is to use Vuex in combination with the vuex-persistedstate plugin. You will then mutate the Vuex state (which will be quietly persisted to LocalStorage on the background) and convert isLoggedIn() to Vuex getter so that it will instantly catch when you login and logout.

Comment: The vue Router has navigation guards  https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards there you can updade dependend on  `from` parameter

Comment: @IVOGELOV, thanks, I thought about that possible solution. That could solve my problem.

Comment: @Estradiaz  I must update my `toolbar` states. Which is not imported. I think Vuex could solve my problem, I'll try it in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the original method of the User at "created" phase.

```
return {
    data () {
        return {
            items: [
                { title: 'Questions', to: '/questions', show: true },
                { title: 'Ask question', to: '/askQuestion', show: true },
                { title: 'Categories', to: '/categories', show: true },
                { title: 'Login/Signup', to: '/login', show: !User.isLoggedIn() },
                { title: 'Log out', to: '/logout', show: User.isLoggedIn() },
            ]
        }
    },
    created () {
        let app = this;
        let items = app.items;
        let loginUser = User.login.bind(User);
        let logoutUser = User.logout.bind(User);

        User.login = () => {
            // modify the data
            items[3].show = false;
            items[4].show = true;
            // do login
            loginUser();
        };

        User.logout = () => {
            // modify the data
            items[3].show = true;
            items[4].show = false;
            // do logout
            logoutUser();
        };
    }
};
```